# Algolia - how can i set uiState in another component

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch, vue-instant-search

Im trying to set uiState in another component in my Vue project.
This is my template, which includes the ais-instant-search component and the function(onStateChange) that is fired when I change the filters in my refinementList:

```
<template>
    <ais-instant-search :index-name="indexName" :search-client="algolia" :on-state-change="onStateChange">
        <div class="home-page-container">
            <HomePage />
        </div>
    </ais-instant-search>
</template>

const onStateChange = ({ uiState, setUiState }: IOnStateChange) => {
    setUiState(uiState)
}
```

At this point I am able to control my uiState. But i need to set it in another component - HomePage for example. How can I acces the setUiState function and manually set the uiState in other component?

I tried to pass the function using provide, but it looks like it doesn't work.